# Received late K1, but do not owe any tax. Must I amend my return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return, schedule-k-1

I received a late K-1 form. I already filed my taxes. Do I need to file an amended return even if I do not owe any additional tax?

Comment: Does it have any values in it at all? Would it decrease your tax, or provide additional cost basis which you could use to reduce your capital gains in the future?

Comment: Anecdotally, this happened to me several years ago. I didn't bother to refile even though maybe I was supposed to amend (no change in taxes owed). Nothing ever happened.